# Change the language of error message required

Tags: javascript, css, html

Is it possible to change the language of the error message required? I know that I can add a message in my language `required title="Message"`, but I want to change the languge of the default: `please fill out this field`. In other words: I do not want to supply a custom text. I want to force a language for the default messages.

I tried setting the lang attribute and also sent a Content-Language header but it always uses the browser's default language instead.

How can I do this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: ah it's quite incomplete your question can you elaborate? Show us what you are trying